# JSF Converter Timestamp

Tags: jsf, timestamp, jsf-2, converters

I want to convert my input into a timestamp value.

I have only found a dateconverter in examples. Are there any best practises?

Thank you

---

Update:

I want to save a birthday of a user but my backend requires a timestamp value. And I have problems with binding it to my jsf frontend..

Maybe a link to an example would be helful :-)

I tried it as follows:

```
public void setBday(Date bday) {
            member.setBirthday(new Timestamp(bday.getTime()));
        }
        public Timestamp getBday() {
            return member.getBirthday();
        }
```

But I get exceptions (strange):

```
/createMember.xhtml @34,54 value="#{member.bday}": Cannot convert 13.01.83 01:00 of type class java.util.Date to class java.sql.Timestamp
```

(Is it maybe because of get method?)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Bind to [`Date#getTime()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#getTime%28%29) instead to get/set the raw timestamp in milliseconds.

```
<h:inputText value="#{bean.date.time}" />
```

Or if you want to input/output a human readable date, then just stick to using `#{bean.date}` and use the standard date converters.

```
<h:inputText value="#{bean.date}">
    <f:convertDateTime type="date" dateType="short" />
</h:inputText>
```

In the backend just use `Date#getTime()` to process the timestamp.

---

**Update**: you shouldn't clutter your model with JDBC specific API. The `java.util.Date` represents the timestamp. Use `java.sql.Timestamp` only at that point you're about to persist a `java.util.Date` in a `TIMESTAMP` or `DATETIME` column of your DB.

```
preparedStatement.setTimestamp(index, new Timestamp(bean.getDate().getTime()));
```

Comment: I don't actually understand your advice :-/ Look at my edited question, please

Comment: I didn't expect that you used `java.sql.Timestamp` in your model. See answer update.

Comment: But what if you are forced to use Timestamp by an underlying API, such as with jBPM: http://community.jboss.org/thread/162961