# how to input a timestamp value in jsf

Tags: java, jsf

how can I input a Timestamp value in my database table from an inputtext

i created a value with type Timestamp in my manager bean but when a do inputText value="#{bean.value} it returns null

Thank you

Comment: You should take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/a/4639400/354831.

Comment: thank you Alexander , i dindn't understand how to useuse Date#getTime() in backend ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [JSF Converter Timestamp](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4639330/jsf-converter-timestamp)

Comment: HII Rafik , actually I need to input a timestamp value I dont unterstand how to Bind to Date#getTime()

Comment: @Omar JSF will not magically convert `String` to `Timestamp` and vice-versa. I suggest usage of `f:convertDateTime` & convert manually `Date` to `Timestamp` prior to load / save DB, ortherwise, create his own JSF converter.

Comment: @AlexandreLavoie, you're right. I forgot that `f:converDateTime` returns `Date` instance to the backing-bean, which requires an additional conversion. Corrected it.